# How Do I Set XML Content-Type in Flex 3?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, content-type

I've got a Flex 3 project. Flex makes an ExternalCall to some Javascript. The Javascript is then turned into XML.

But, my xml isn't parsing in IE. It works in all other browsers. I think that the problem is that I haven't set the XML's content-type and IE doesn't like that. So my code looks like:

```
myReturn =  '<myXMLReturn>' + myReturn + '</myXMLReturn>';

myReturn = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' + myReturn;

xmlReturn = new XML(myReturn);
```

How would I set: header('Content-type: application/xml'); in Actionscript?

As I understand it IE requires that the Content-type be set. Is this correct?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Comment: Can you give more details about your problem ?

Comment: Hi redben
Thank you for the message. The crux of my problem is that xmlReturn won't parse. So, xmlReturn.a.img.@src; is producing nothing. I validated the xml in http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp and it looked okay. I thought that maybe IE didn't like the headers or the lack of Content-type. If you have any suggestions, I'd love to hear them. I'm coming up blank. Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, everyone. My bug actually turned out to be a case sensitivity problem in parsing the XML. I didn't need to set the Content-type.